# Import copy, has the error TypeError: object does not support item assignment on output

Tags: python, python-2.4

I'm learning OReilly - Python Standard Library through some core module in Chapter 1.
I use the code below and it run successful.

```
import copy

a = [[1],[2],[3]]
b = copy.copy(a)
c = copy.copy(b)

print "\nbefore", "=>"
print a
print b
print c

# modify original
a[0][0] = 0
*a[1] = None*
a[2] = "Thanks"

print "after", "=>"
print a
print b
print c
```

And the output is :

```
before =>
[[1], [2], [3]]
[[1], [2], [3]]
after =>
[[0], None, 'Thanks']
[[0], [2], [3]]
```

But when I tried to change some code with use copy.deepcopy(), I met an error on the output but didn't relate to copy.deepcopy().

```
import copy

a = [4],[7],[19]
b = copy.deepcopy(a)

print "\nBefore", "=>"
print a
print b

# modify the original
a[0][0] = 2
*a[1] = "I don't know how to say"*

print "After", "=>"
print a
print b
```

The error output is below :

```
Before =>
([4], [7], [19])
([4], Traceback (most recent call last):
[7], [19])
  File "C:\Users\HP\workspace\Python-Student\OReilly - Python Standard Library - Source Code\Chapter 1. Core Modules\1.12 The copy Module\copy-example-2.py", line 12, in ?
    **a[1] = "I don't know how to say"**
TypeError: object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: Why on earth are you using Python 2.4?

Comment: This question isn't to do with `copy` or `deepcopy`. Remove all the `copy` related code and you will still have a valid question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I'm learning Python, so I followed the python version in this book. I know you will say why don't you use Python 2.7 or 3, actually alot of my servers are using Python 2.4 so this is the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that in the second script `a` is a tuple as you are creating `a` using -

```
a = [4],[7],[19]
```

So, if you print `a` it would be like -

```
([4], [7], [19])
```

And you cannot directly assign values to `tuple`.

The first code works, because there you are creating `a` as a list -

```
a = [[1],[2],[3]]
```

*Tuples are immutable* , you cannot directly change its value, so you cannot do something like -

```
a[1] = <something else>
```

It does not cause error when you do `a[0][0]` because at that time you are not directly, modifying the tuple , tuple would still point to the same list, but instead you are only modifying the list at the `0th` position.

This error has nothing to do with using `copy.deepcopy()` , you should create `a` as a list, as in your first code, for the second code to work.

Answer (score 3):

```
a = [[1],[2],[3]]
```

What is the type of a? It is a list.

```
a = [4],[7],[19]
```

What is the type of a? It is a tuple.

Tuple is immutable. You can't assign value to it. You missed the [ ] part.
Try:

```
a = [ [4],[7],[19] ]
```

Comment: I tried with your advise above and it works. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to know that. If it helps as you desired, please accept the answer

Answer (score 3):

It is because `tuple are immutable`

And you are creating a tuple :

```
a = [4],[7],[19]
print a
([4],[7],[19])
```

It did not show error here because you are changing the list in a `tuple`

```
a[0][0] = 2
```

Comment: @JackVo that is because you are changing the list inside of the tuple and not the tuple.If you want to change a[1] just do assignment after a[1][1] this will only work for this case

Answer (score 1):

We can not update value in tuple because **tuple data type is immutable**

Exception is Not related to copy statements, It related to tuple data type

**Demo**:

variable a as list, list data type is mutable.

```
>>> a = [[1],[2],[3]]
>>> type(a)
<type 'list'>
>>> a
[[1], [2], [3]]
>>> a[2] = "Thanks"
>>> a
[[1], [2], 'Thanks']
```

Variable a as tuple:

```
>>> a = [4],[7],[19]
>>> type(a)
<type 'tuple'>
>>> a
([4], [7], [19])
>>> a[2] = "Thanks"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
>>>
```